# How to add foreign key in table using existing column, without losing data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I need to add foreign key on an existing column. Following is create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `itemtx` (
  `itemTxid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemcode` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txtype` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'Pickup',
  `tripstopid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bagcount` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemTxid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33524 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to add foreign key on tripstopid column. I cannot drop or empty table as it contains data. Following is the referenced table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tripstop` (
  `tripstopid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tripid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locationName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locationid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createts` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tripstopid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4691 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How can I do this without losing my data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by following:

```
ALTER TABLE itemtx
ADD FOREIGN KEY (tripstopid) REFERENCES tripstop(tripstopid);
```

Verified by creating tables, inserting data in them and then updating table for foreign key, previously entered data is not lost.

Comment: It is showing error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: There are a lot of records in tables. I cannot show them here. In your opinion, what could be the case?

Comment: Take 2-3 records from each table, and create sql-fiddle for further investigation.

Comment: It might be failing in a case, when you have tripstopid in itemtx that doesn't exist in tripstop . Therefore, first you might need to update tripstopid in itemtx to some default value that exists in tripstop.